# addEventListener executa uma função antes mesmo de ser chamada

Tags: javascript

Eu gostaria de saber por qual motivo essa função está sendo executada antes mesmo do `click`.

```
function teste(){
    console.log("teste");
}

addEventListener("click", teste());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) deve receber uma função (ou um [`EventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)) no segundo parâmetro.

Mas ao fazer `teste()` (com os parênteses), você está **chamando** a função (**executando-a**), e o retorno dela é passado para `addEventListener` (no caso, a função não retorna nada, mas o que importa aqui é o fato de que você está executando a função, quando na verdade deveria passá-la como parâmetro).

Para passar a função como parâmetro, basta retirar os parênteses. Exemplo:

```js
function teste(){
    console.log("teste");
}

document.getElementById('clica').addEventListener("click", teste);
//                                       sem os parênteses ^^^^^
```

```html
<div id="clica">Clique em mim</div>
```

Com isso, `addEventListener` recebe a função que será executada quando o evento `click` ocorrer.

Colocando `teste` sem parênteses estou indicando que a função que vai ser executada é `teste`, mas ela não deve ser executada agora (no momento em que `addEventListener` é chamado), e sim quando o evento `click` ocorre.

Comment: Realmente voce esta 100% certo! funcionou perfeitamente sem os (), mas por que ele funcionou sem os () sendo que isso que executa uma funcao? o fato seria, o () executa a funcao, e quem deve executar a funcao seria o evento do addeventlistner? eu colocando nao colocando os parentes teste ele meio que fica aguardando uma execucao por alguma funcao? que no caso seria a de callback do listner? desculpe se eu nao soube me expressar

Comment: @BrunoBafilli Porque `teste` (sem parênteses) é uma referência para a função (é como se fosse uma "variável" que "contém" a função) . Já `teste()` (com parênteses) é uma chamada para a função (estou de fato executando ela). Adicionei uma explicação na resposta, veja se esclarece sua dúvida

Comment: A responsabilidade de executar a função é do EventListener, por isso não se usa parênteses. Digamos que é o próprio EventListener que "coloca os parênteses" na função no momento apropriado. É um callback, como você mencionou.

Comment: Otima explicacao, eu agradeco muito pela atencao e disposicao de tempo para a explicacao, tenha um otimo dia e bons estudos para todos.

Answer (score 0):

A onde ele tem que ser clicado? Você não definiu isso.

Exemplo, supondo que queira clicar em um botão:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Botão foi clicado!');
});
```

```css
button {
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #3e3e3e;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<button>Clique</button>
```